# как выровнять карточки css

Tags: css, materialize-css

есть карточка а внутри нее разное количество контента.
Как выровнять все карточки с разным контентом по высоте.

Может кто знает фреймверк [materialize](https://materializecss.com/cards.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задать фиксированную высоту карточки.
В этом фреймворке есть три класса для карточек - `small`, `medium`, `large`. Высота 300, 400 и 500px соответственно.
Например, используя класс `small` у вас получатся карточки высотой 300px:

```
    <div class="card small">
    <!-- Card Content -->
    </div>
```

Пример https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VEXvpd